# Couldn't compile opencv4nodejs in Vue + electron application

Tags: node.js, vue.js, opencv, electron-builder

I am trying to build a face detection application with opencv4nodejs, vue + electron-builder. During the process of application setup I cam across a problem where I get the following error during npm run serve after installing opencv4nodejs.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build/Release/opencv4nodejs.node 1:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

It would be great if some one can help me with it. Thank you in advance

Update: I have added my view.config.js for reference

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module;
    // add ts files
    //      .rule('ts')
    //      .use('ts-loader')
    //        .loader('ts-loader')
    //        .tap(options => {
    // modify the options...
    //          return options
    //        })
  }
};
```

Comment: Please share your webpack.config file.

Comment: Hello @Eldar I have added the vue.config.js file for reference

Comment: Add externals to webpack https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: You need to add [node loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/node-loader/) to load `.node` files with webpack

Comment: @Eldar Exactly worked for my issues thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As our friend @Eldar commented adding node-loader to vue.config.js works for me. Thank you

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module       .rule('ts')
        .use('ts-loader')
        .loader('ts-loader')
        .end()
        .rule(/\.node$/)
        .use('node-loader')
        .loader('node-loader')
        .end()
  }
};
```

Hope this is useful folks.